# Find linear combinations of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I tried but I was not able to find similar questions. If there are duplicate questions, please give me the link.

I saw someone asked an interesting algorithm problem on a forum. The problem asks how many ways can you split 106 into a linear combination of 10, 20, 50, 1, 2 and 5? For instance, 106=10*6+1*6, 106=50*2+2*1+1*4.

I used python to resolve this problem, but it is super slow. And I also generalized my function so it can be applied to not only 106 but also other numbers.

Is there any way to make my algorithm faster? It takes me minutes to get 160 ways, which is a very small part of the all solutions and I don't have the patience to wait for more results because as recursion goes one solution will take more and more time.

```
def main(total,*args):
    def recursion(Sum,method):          
        for arg in args:
            if Sum<arg:
                continue
            method[arg]+=1
            if Sum>arg:
                recursion(Sum-arg,method)
            else:
                methods.append(method.copy())
            method[arg]-=1
    methods=[]
    recursion(total,{ arg:0 for arg in args})
    return len(methods)

main(106,10,20,50,1,2,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the coin change problem. You can refer to the below link for various approach for solutions:
[coin change problem gfg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Comment: Thanks! Recursion is way too slow.

Comment: Is there a way to find all the combinations instead of merely the number of combinations?

Comment: To find all the combinations you have to try every permutation using the recursion approach which will be very slow.